# Method reference pop-up unreadable

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

There is a pop-up thing that explains what the code does and it looks like this:

[image]

But after I updated to a newer version of Visual Studio, it changed to this:

[image]

It is harder to read if you ask me.
I'm using Visual Studio Community 2019 (16.7.6)
How can I fix this?

Comment: That's strange, my copy updated to 16.7.6 doesn't have that colouring. Have you tried changing the theme to light and then back to dark? "Tools" - > "Options..." -> "Environment" -> "General" then the "Color Theme" is in a dropdown in the pane on the right.

Comment: I did what you said and it's fixed! Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The colour settings for the pop-up appear to be faulty.

You can reset them by going into the "Tools" menu -> "Options..." -> "Environment" -> "General" then the "Color Theme" is in a dropdown in the pane on the right.

Change it to something else and then back to "Dark".

[image]